# Cannot highlight text on my Kindle Paperwhite using a sample ebook

Tags: amazon, kindle-paperwhite

I have a sample ebook from Amazon on my Kindle Paperwhite but I cannot highlight its text due to the option being grayed out. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's by design. Samples are basically marketing material and Amazon doesn't want to provide full functionality of a Kindle eBook with them, in hopes to give users another plus factor to buy the eBook.

Comment: I cannot highlight sample books on the physical kindle either, but i can highlight the same sample book using the kindle app on my iPhone.

Comment: However I can highlight in a Kindle sample that is in the Kindle app on my tablet or smartphone. So why the difference?